# How Trigger Element event synchronously in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#inp').focus();
    console.log('two');
  });
  $('#inp').focus(function() {
    console.log('one');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">
            Click
        </button>
<input type="text" id="inp">
```

If you run the above snippet in Chrome the out put will be

```
one
two
```

When you run in IE the out put is

```
two
one
```

How to make it synchronous in IE?

Comment: You can never be sure with functions in JavaScript. Whenever an anonymous function is created it is thrown on a stack to be executed, but there is no way of knowing when exactly this will happen.

Comment: azad, it's working for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use [triggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) method.

> .triggerHandler() returns whatever value was returned by the last
>   handler it caused to be executed. If no handlers re triggered, it
>   returns undefined

`console.log('two')` will only run when focus event is finished.

```
$(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#inp').triggerHandler('focus');
    console.log('two');
   });
  $('#inp').focus(function() {
    console.log('one');
  });
});
```